# Can't create a new inctence of class that is part of web service

Tags: web-services, constructor, windows-store-apps

I'm using in my windows sore app in webservice.
In the webservie I have the following class :

```
public class User
{
    private string lastName, firstName, email, password, cellPhone;
    public User(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string phone, string password)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.cellPhone = phone;
        this.password = password;
    }
    public User(){}

}
```

When I tried to create a new instence of it in the windows store app I used the following code:

```
    ASMXWebServiceReference.User newUser = new ASMXWebServiceReference.User(FirstName.Text, LastName.Text, Email.Text, PhoneNumber.Text, Password.Password);
```

But I got this error:

> 'ASMXWebServiceReference.User' does not contain a constructor that
>   takes 5 arguments

When I create a new instence of users with default contructor I don't have that error.
Why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Password is the name of a textbox, isn't it? I actually didn't see a property like "Password" that belongs to textbox class. Did you try Password.Text?